# What is the resolution for this Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Quick Start Program Exception?

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have just started learning Microsoft Dynamics 2011 online and while I ran the Quick Start sample code provided in the SDK, it threw me the following exception [In the image]

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: ...
>   The remote name could not be resolved: ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool expects the address of the Discovery Service. As it looks like you would connect to the APAC data-center, you have to specify `crm5.dynamics.com`

In total there are three Discovery Service endpoints for Dynamics CRM Online

- https://dev.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc   (North America)
- https://dev.crm4.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc  (EMEA)
- https://dev.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc (APAC)

Note that the complete path has to include `/XRMServices/2011/Discovery.svc` and has to start with `dev` (the tool adds this automatically).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328127.aspx